# How do I distinguish -std=c++17 and -std=gnu++17 at compile time? checking macros?

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, std

I am using the `__int128` extension of g++. The problem with `-std=c++17` is that some of the C++ library does not have all the support for that extension (i.e. `std::make_unsigned<>` fails). When using `-std=gnu++17` it works fine.

I've added a header file that allows for the `<limit>` to work with `__int128` when using `-std=c++17` and I'd like to keep it for now, but when using `-std=gnu++17` it breaks (because it is already defined). So I was thinking to add a condition like so:

```
#if !(<something>)
...
#endif
```

if the compiler already supports the limits with `__int128`.

My question is: what is that `<something>` I could check  to distinguish between the standard and the GNU c++17 libraries?

Comment: Have you checked [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I did, and it wasn't very helpful. Maybe I didn't look in the right place. It suggested that `__GNUC__` would be set if the extensions were available (`__int128` is a C extension also available in C++, AIUI), but when I tested that, it turned out that it's defined with both `-std=c++17` and `-std=gnu++17`, so it didn't seem to be the solution sought. Of course, it would be useful to see actual code which shows the problem OP refers to.

Comment: According to GNU documentation, gnu compilers define the macro `__STRICT_ANSI__` if compiled with `-std`, and don't define it otherwise - and it is used by GNU libc's headers to limit itself to using only features in the standard.    The standard also requires that a C++17 compiler should have the macro `__cplusplus` with the value `201703L`  (and more recent standards will have larger values).    I expect those two macros should, in combination, provide a way to meet meet your requirement.

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/limits#L1634 - hah, you can add your own types with `__GLIBCXX_TYPE/BITSIZE_INT_N_0/1/2/3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this:

```bash
$ diff <(g++-11 -std=c++17 -E -dM -x c++ /dev/null|LC_ALL=C sort) \
       <(g++-11 -std=gnu++17 -E -dM -x c++ /dev/null|LC_ALL=C sort)
```

And the output was:

```
180a181,182
> #define __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0 128
> #define __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0 __int128
315d316
< #define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1
424a426,427
> #define linux 1
> #define unix 1
```

That's not definitive, of course, but it's maybe a start.

So you could check for `__STRICT_ANSI__` (indicating that there are no Gnu extensions), but perhaps the undocumentable `__GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0` is more direct.

Comment: Oh. It looks like it was [made available even in C++11](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20160718/165415.html) (but since Jul 2016).

Comment: Here is a direct link to the [corresponding PR](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/23530).